# Ansible-playbook trying to run a command inside a command to grab the variable. OR a better way to do it

Tags: ansible, yaml, nvidia

It seems as though uname -r is not being executed the way I think it should. I've tried several variations.

```
- name: install nvidia driver with kernel module
  command: /root/{{ nvidia_driver }} -a -s --kernel-source-path /usr/src/kernels/'{uname -r}'
```

Error:

```
TASK [portal : install nvidia driver with kernel module] 

*****************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.188.115]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/root/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.66.run", "-a", "-s", "--kernel-source-path", "/usr/src/kernels/{uname -r}"], "delta": "0:00:12.120560", "end": "2020-09-22 14:59:06.201662", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-09-22 14:58:54.081102", "stderr": "./nvidia-installer: unrecognized option: \"-r}\"\n\nERROR: Invalid commandline, please run `./nvidia-installer --help` for usage information.", "stderr_lines": ["./nvidia-installer: unrecognized option: \"-r}\"", "", "ERROR: Invalid commandline, please run `./nvidia-installer --help` for usage information."], "stdout": "Verifying archive integrity... OK\nUncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 450.66................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................", "stdout_lines": ["Verifying archive integrity... OK", "Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 450.66................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `uname -r` is not returning the kernel version that you are expecting.

You should use the `ansible_kernel` Ansible fact in your command.

```yaml
- name: install nvidia driver with kernel module
  command: "/root/{{ nvidia_driver }} -a -s --kernel-source-path /usr/src/kernels/{{ ansible_kernel }}"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly after I enabled gather_facts and then did an update to regather facts right before this part. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Good to know. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `'{uname -r}'` is incorrect syntax for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).
That's why the error say `-r` is unrecognized option.
You could try with `$(uname -r)`.